# Add median survival line to ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, median, survival-analysis

I have been looking the whole morning for the following: 
I have a survival object

```
myData.KMfit <- npsurv(Surv(Time, myData$todurs=="dead") ~ myData$Sex);
```

which I display using:

```
plot <- ggsurvplot(myData.KMfit,pval=TRUE,risk.table=TRUE,risk.table.col = "strata", main="Sex specific survival",legend="top",legend.title="Sex",legend.labs=c("Women","Men"));
```

The plot looks like this
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySeCW.jpg)

I would like to add a line at `y = 0.5` for median survival. However, I could not find a solution so far.

Who can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

the option is  surv.median.line = "hv"  in the ggsurvplot options.

```
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(
          fit,                     
      data = lung,             
      risk.table = TRUE,       
       pval = TRUE,             
   conf.int = TRUE,         
 surv.median.line = "hv",  # add the median survival pointer.
     legend.labs = 
        c("Male", "Female")    # change legend labels.
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack is to add `ggtheme=theme_bw()` or `ggtheme=theme_minimal()` to the end of your `ggsurvplot()` statement -- this will draw lines at the quartiles.